# Python : Getting the Row which has the closest value to 5 in groups using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the row with the closest value to 5 based on another column of a groupby.

Assume the groupby column is called 'ticker' the 'apply' column is called 'YTC'. There are multiple identical values of ticker.

A similar solution is shown below for max. I want to find the closest number to 5 however, not the max.

```
df1.groupby("Ticker")["YTC"].max())
```

Ideally the code would output a dataframe for the value of 'Ticker' that is closest to 5.

Comment: Create a new colum where you substract 5, power (-1) and use .max()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it without `groupby` by sorting + `drop_duplicates`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': list('aabbccddeeeeefff'),
                   'YTC': np.random.randint(1,10,16)})

df[['Ticker', 'YTC']].assign(delta=(df.YTC-5).abs()).sort_values('delta').drop_duplicates('Ticker').drop(columns='delta')
#   Ticker  YTC
#12      e    5
#15      f    5
#4       c    4
#0       a    3
#2       b    7
#6       d    2
```

The index is the original index of the `DataFrame` for the row on which the closest value occurs, which can be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the perfect solution